# Azure Durable Function run via Docker Container returns 403 over HTTPS (but works OK over HTTP)

Tags: azure, docker, http, https, azure-functions

I'm trying to get a Durable Function to run in a Docker container. I'm only able to get it to work when I call my orchestration starter function using HTTP. If I try to kick off the orchestration over HTTPS, I get a 403 unauthorized error; in the portal, my app is published with an HTTPS URL, and I also get a 403 trying to access that.

More context: I'm deploying the function through Azure DevOps using Terraform. This is a function that we've had running successfully for over a year before we started the conversion to Docker containers.

I think this could at least partly be due to Docker + Azure Functions + TLS termination. We were able to get around this with our dockerized Web App by creating an appseting "Kestrel__Endpoints__Http__Url" and setting the value of that to the port specified in the Dockerfile. For this function, I'm setting the port to 80 in the Dockerfile.

Let me know if more details are needed.

I've tried "Kestrel__Endpoints__Http__Url" appsetting trick, that doesn't do anything. And to clarify my earlier point: If I initiate the orchestration using  **http**://example.azurewebsites.net/api/OrchestrationStarter everything works fine, but if I do it over **https**://example.azurewebsites.net/api/OrchestrationStarter I get a 403 error. And I want to run it over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who may run into this issue in the future, my problem was this: I was using the incorrect azure functions docker image. Previously, I was using `azure-functions/dotnet:4`, when I needed to be using `azure-functions/dotnet:4-dotnet6-appservice`. Everything runs as expected over HTTPS since making that one change in my Dockerfile.